# How do you get multiple if statements working within the same open office calc cell

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I am trying to sort a column out in open office and need the cell values to stay between 10 and 0. I currently have an If statement as follows: `If(X6>0;(((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5;0)`
I need to also include an IF statement in the same cell as follows: `IF(X6>10;$D$26=0;(((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5)`

How can I get these 2 IF statements to work within the same cell?

Answer (score 2):

The "then" and "else" parts in `if(condition; then; else)` can be an IF statement too:

```
if(condition1; then1; else if(condition2; then2; else2))
if(x6<=0; 0; if(x6>10; $D$26=0; (((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5))
```

Or:

```
if(condition1; then if(condition2; then2; else2); else1)
if(x6>0; if(x6>10; $D$26=0; (((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5); 0)
```

Comment: ...but I'm not sure what the `$D$26=0` in your original formula does though...

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two `IF` expressions in your question:

`If(X6>0;           (((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5; 0)`         (with spaces added for clarity)   and
`IF(X6>10; $D$26=0; (((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5)`

I present them like this
because it’s not obvious from the question that the

```
                   (((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5
```

subexpression is the same in both.<sup>†</sup> 
[Arjan’s answer](//superuser.com/q/1162079/354511#1162082) is correct, but it depends on the fact that your two `IF` expressions have a common subexpression.

I also wonder what you intend the `$D$26=0` subexpression to do. 
If it’s a typo, and you mean

```
IF(X6>10;     0  ; (((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5)
```

then there’s another answer that (IMHO) is clearer:

```
IF(AND(X6>0;X6<=10); (((S7/V7)-($B$6))/$B$4)+$X$5; 0)
```

Note that your text says “between 10 and 0”,
but you are treating 0 and 10 differently.
____________
<sup>†</sup> By the way,
you can simplify this subexpression a little
by removing excess parentheses. 
You can simplify it to any of the following:

- `(((S7/V7)-$B$6)/$B$4)+$X$5`
- `((S7/V7-$B$6)/$B$4)+$X$5`
- `(S7/V7-$B$6)/$B$4+$X$5`